# Moving A Point Along Ellipse

Tags: javascript, math, drawing, ellipse

I have created an ellipse on my canvas and now I need to draw three lines stemming from the origin. As an example let's say the first line is 90 degrees (vertical) so the point is (0, 10). I need the other two lines to be x pixels away from the point in both directions.

I'm sure I didn't describe this well enough but basically what I am trying to do is from a point on a known ellipse, find another point x distance away that lies on the ellipse.

I have tried looking for an arc of an ellipse but nothing seems to fit what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you know the minimum and maximum values for the ellipse's radius?

Comment: Yes, I am drawing the ellipse so I know every point.

Comment: So, Andrew Morton was faster than me, see his answer.

Comment: You said “the first line is 90 degrees (vertical) so the point is (10, 0)”.  A line from (0,0) to (10,0) is horizontal, not vertical.  Did you mean the first point is (0, 10)?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was getting late in the day :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an ellipse:

```
x = a cos(t)
y = b sin(t)
```

So:

```
x/a= cos(t)
t = acos(x/a)
y = b sin(acos(x/a))
```

Plug in your values of `a`, `b`, and `x` and you get `y`.

See https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html

Rather crudely:

```js
var a=120;
var b=70;

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt=c.getContext("2d");

var xCentre=c.width / 2;
var yCentre=c.height / 2;


// draw axes
cxt.strokeStyle='blue';
cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(0, yCentre);
cxt.lineTo(xCentre*2, yCentre);
cxt.stroke();

cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(xCentre, 0);
cxt.lineTo(xCentre, yCentre*2);
cxt.stroke();

// draw ellipse
cxt.strokeStyle='black';

cxt.beginPath();

for (var i = 0 * Math.PI; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 0.01 ) {
    xPos = xCentre - (a * Math.cos(i));
    yPos = yCentre + (b * Math.sin(i));

    if (i == 0) {
        cxt.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
    } else {
        cxt.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
    }
}
cxt.lineWidth = 2;
cxt.strokeStyle = "#232323";
cxt.stroke();
cxt.closePath();

// draw lines with x=+/- 40
var deltaX=40;

var y1=b*Math.sin(Math.acos(deltaX/a));

cxt.strokeStyle='red';
cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(xCentre+deltaX, yCentre-y1);
cxt.lineTo(xCentre, yCentre);
cxt.lineTo(xCentre-deltaX, yCentre-y1);
cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Ellipse</title></head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="position: absolute;" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

(Using https://www.scienceprimer.com/draw-oval-html5-canvas as a basis as I've never used HTML canvas before.)

Comment: This finds me the y value of a point I already know. From a point directly over the origin, let's say (0, 15) I need to find a point to the "right" x distance and a point to the "left" x distance. These two other points must fall on the ellipse. Sorry if your answer explains this but I don't see how it will "move along the ellipse". So the ARC should be a length of 5.

Comment: You say you want a point on the ellipse which is x pixels to the right. Say x=10.0, then y=b sin(acos(10.0/a)). For x pixels to the left, you want y=b sin(acos(-10.0/a)). You know the values of a and b because you used them to draw the ellipse.

Comment: I think I'm confused on the math and logic then. When I say I want a point 10 pixels to the left and currently X = 10. My new point should be < 10 because the arc of the ellipse isn't a straight line. I should get an answer slightly greater than 0. I may be asking for too much but let's say the point is closer to a horizontal endpoint then I don't want the x point to be directly 10 to the left/right because of the curve.

Comment: @AdamDev Then I think you are talking about an arc length along the ellipse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse . Saying "left" means "left", not "left a bit and down a bit" ;) Rather than trying for an exact measurement via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral , you might get away with pretending the ellipse is a circle and using the arc length of that. The inaccuracy may not be visible/obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew Morton's answer is adequate, but you can it with one square root instead of a `sin` and an `acos`.

Suppose you have an ellipse centered at the origin, with a radius along the X-axis of *a* and a radius along the Y-axis of *b*.  The equation of this ellipse is

> *x*<sup>2</sup>/*a*<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>/*b*<sup>2</sup> = 1.

Solving this for *y* gives

> *y* = ± *b* sqrt(1 - *x*<sup>2</sup>/*a*<sup>2</sup>)

You can choose whichever sign is appropriate.  Based on your post, you want the positive square root.

Translating to Javascript:

```
function yForEllipse(a, b, x) {
    return b * Math.sqrt(1 - x*x / a * a);
}
```